# How to add column to a table which contain millions of data

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I need to add an additional column to live DB table which contain millions of data. I'm using maria 10.0. Is there any tools? or Can anyone suggest a better method for this process.

Comment: I don't really see much of a way to speed this up, other then the possible issue of the indices which already exist on your table.  If adding a new column would force an index rebuild, maybe you can look into turning off/dropping the indices before you add the new column.

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/11/18/avoiding-mysql-alter-table-downtime/

Comment: I'm not saying it's a great idea, but you *coukd* construct an annexe table that simply joins to your existing table in a 1-1 relationship

Comment: @Strawberry If I construct an annexe table, I have to put additional join which will cause slow down the other processes.

Comment: Is that a statement or a question?

Comment: @Strawberry What I meant was, I have already tried your suggestion. It works as I expect. But it'll reduce the performance as I add an additional Join to the annexe table. That's why I'm looking for another option. :D

Comment: The extra `JOIN` might not cost that much.  And the new table need have only as many rows as you have values.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 10.3 has an "instand add column" feature that makes such an operation really fast.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/instant-add-column-for-innodb/

As MariaDB 10.0 reaches its end of life ("EOL") this month, an update to a more recent release should be considered now, anyway?

Comment: MySQL 8.0 also has the instant add column.  This feature is an example of someone not working for Oracle or MariaDB contributing the code.

Comment: Right ... I had this question in my "mariadb" tag stream, didn't notice that it was also tagged "mysql", too